# How can i calculate mean value of numpy matrix by column using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy matrix data with dimensions of 900x256. And i need to reduce number of columns by calculating mean for each 30 rows of matrix. As results matrix should be 30x256 dimensions. how can i do that?

Comment: I assume you mean each 30 rows of the matrix?

Comment: yes each 30 rows

Comment: see my answer..think it does what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the OP says reduce the number of columns, but the desired result still has 256 columns, I think you meant to reduce the rows?

is this what you had in mind?

```
print(arr.shape) # (900,256)
means = np.array([arr[i*step:i*step+step].mean(axis=0) for i in range(int(len(arr)/step))])
print(means.shape) #(30,256)
```

this breaks the array into chunks of 30 rows and takes the column-wise mean for each 30rowx256col chunk.